# In IOS 7 - How do I combine 2 elements of a plist to create one that will show in a tableview cell - First Name + LastName = FirstName LastName

Tags: oop, ios7, uitableview, plist

If I have a plist:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com  /DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>FirstName</key>
    <array>
    <string>Dave</string>
    </array>
    <key>LastName</key>
    <array>
    <string>Smith</string>
    </array>
    <key>Phone</key>
    <array>
    <string>(423) 555-7799</string>
    </array>
    <key>Email</key>
    <array>
    <string>email@gmail.com</string>
    </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

and I am trying to put the first and last name together into a Tableview as one element.

First Name + LastName = FirstName LastName

Dave + Smith = Dave Smith  <<<== This is what I am trying to do!!

I can get the FirstName to show up and the Email in the details but I am trying to combine the first and last name to show as:

Dave Smith

instead of what I now see

Dave

of course this is what I use to show the actual names

**Changed this**

```
cell.textLabel.text = [fname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**To this per Larme**

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [fname  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [lname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

**And it works as intended!**

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [email objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

If the complete .m file is needed I can add it I think

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [fname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [lname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`? With `lname` the array of lastnames

Comment: Larme - Thank you for that. I thought I had it correct but it would not work and you gave me the information I was needing.